# Find out when refresh is called

Tags: react-admin

I have a custom component that I am showing in one of an edit page using react-admin.

For react-admin components, whenever the refresh button is clicked, the page updates automatically with the results from the server. But for my component, I need to manually update the component whenever refresh has been clicked.

[Refresh button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgCqC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure something out to reload. I am calling a loadUsersFromProps whenever the component received props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.loadUsersFromProps(nextProps);
}

loadUsersFromProps(nextProps) {
    const userIDs = this.state.selectedUsers.map(user => user.userID);
    this.loadFromRecord(this.props, nextProps, 'userIDs', userIDs, this.fetchAndLoadUsersByIDs);
}

loadFromRecord(currProps, nextProps, key, stateValue, loadFunction) {
    let reloadRequired = false;
    if (nextProps.record && nextProps.record[key]) {
        if (currProps.record) {
            if (nextProps.record[key] !== currProps.record[key]) {
                reloadRequired = true;
            }
        } else {
            reloadRequired = true;
        }
        if (nextProps.record[key] !== stateValue) {
            reloadRequired = true;
        }
        if (reloadRequired) {
            loadFunction(nextProps.record[key]);
        }
    }
}
```